# How do I get the value of a textbox inside a controller and give it to another outside the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page that mainly uses controllers and I'd like to paste the value of a textbox inside a controller to another element on the actual page, how should I go about doing this?

Here is the object inside the controller (SadlOwner.ascx)

```
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 0px;">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <span class="input-group-addon input-group-addon-pireus" id="lbSadlCrsCode">CRS code:</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-pireus mandatory" id="SadlCrsCode" runat="server" aria-describedby="lbSadlCrsCode" data-taggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" maxlength="20">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSadlChoiceEGN" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-pireus input-group-addon input-group-addon-sm" aria-describedby="lbSadlEGN" OnClick="btnSadlChoiceEGN_Click" ToolTip="Избор клиент на Банката">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the other one is inside another controller (SadlData.ascx) that needs to get the value of the previous.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does one controller control the creation of the other (i.e. a partial view inside a partial view)? Are they both being created by a governing "master" controller (e.g. the main view)? We can't know on what level to implement the passing of data if we don't know the structure.

Comment: You could use `Session`

Comment: Have you mean "user control" to another "user control"? You can use client-side events handling or session state during postback to do so.

Comment: One of the controllers generates the other, yes.

Comment: Aside from the question (I don't have a clue unfortunately) just an FYI from seeing `"glyphicon` that bootstrap will be removing icons from their build as other providers already do a better job. soon it will be removed so beware (I use font-awesome now for this reason)

Comment: Are you sure? Where can I read about this, I've got a lot of websites built using mostly the icons ;/